# How to work TightVNC in web browser

Tags: tightvnc

TightVNC has provides this file for embedding in web pages(`Java Viewer`):

https://www.tightvnc.com/download/2.8.3/tvnjviewer-2.8.3-bin-gnugpl.zip

`viewer-applet-example.html` in the file, provides a example:

the `<applet>` loading jar(`tightvnc-jviewer.jar`),object(`com.glavsoft.viewer.Viewer`)

the `<param>` set ip(`localhost`),port(`5900`)...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TightVNC desktop</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet archive="tightvnc-jviewer.jar"
        code="com.glavsoft.viewer.Viewer"
        width="100" height="100">
    <param name="Host" value="localhost"/>
    <!-- Host to connect. Default:  the host from which the applet was loaded. -->
    <param name="Port" value="5900"/>
    <!-- Port number to connect. Default: 5900 -->
    <!--param name="Password" value="" /--> <!-- Password to the server (not recommended to use this parameter here) -->
    <param name="OpenNewWindow" value="yes"/>
    <!-- yes/true or no/false. Default: yes/true -->
    <param name="ShowControls" value="yes"/>
    <!-- yes/true or no/false. Default: yes/true -->
    <param name="ViewOnly" value="no"/>
    <!-- yes/true or no/false. Default: no/false -->
    <param name="AllowClipboardTransfer" value="yes"/>
    <!-- yes/true or no/false. Default: yes/true -->
    <param name="RemoteCharset" value="standard"/>
    <!-- Charset encoding is used on remote system. Use this option to specify character encoding will be used for encoding clipboard text content to. Default value (when parameter is empty): local system default character encoding. Set the value to 'standard' for using 'Latin-1' charset which is only specified by rfb standard for clipboard transfers. -->

    <param name="ShareDesktop" value="yes"/>
    <!-- yes/true or no/false. Default: yes/true -->
    <param name="AllowCopyRect" value="yes"/>
    <!-- yes/true or no/false. Default: yes/true -->
    <param name="Encoding" value="Tight"/>
    <!-- Possible values: "Tight", "Hextile", "ZRLE", and "Raw". Default: Tight -->
    <param name="CompressionLevel" value=""/>
    <!-- 1-9 or empty. Empty means server default -->
    <param name="JpegImageQuality" value=""/>
    <!-- 1-9, Lossless or empty. When param is set to "Lossless" no jpeg compression used. Empty means server default -->
    <param name="LocalPointer" value="On"/>
    <!-- Possible values: on/yes/true (draw pointer locally), off/no/false (let server draw pointer), hide). Default: "On"-->
    <param name="ConvertToASCII" value="no"/>
    <!-- Whether to convert keyboard input to ASCII ignoring locale. Possible values: yes/true, no/false). Default: "No"-->

    <param name="Tunneling" value="auto"/>
    <!-- Tunneling. Possible values:
        auto - allow viewer to choose tunneling mode,
        none/no - no tunneling use,
        SSL - choose SSL tunneling when available.
        Default: "auto" -->

    <param name="colorDepth" value=""/>
    <!-- Reserved for future. Possible values: 6, 8, 16, 24, 32 (equals to 24). Only 24/32 is supported now -->
    <param name="ScalingFactor" value="100"/>
    <!-- Scale local representation of the remote desktop on startup. Default is 100 means 100% -->
    <!--param name="showConnectionDialog" value="yes" /-->
    <!-- Set to "No" if you want not to show initial connection dialog. Default: "Yes". -->
    <param name="AppletGoodbyeURL" value="about:blank"/>
    <!-- URL to be redirected on applet stopping. When blank or absent stop applet and do nothing. -->
    <!-- SSH tunneling options -->
    <param name="sshHost" value=""/>
    <!-- SSH host name. -->
    <param name="sshUser" value=""/>
    <!-- SSH port number. When empty, standard SSH port number (22) is used -->
    <param name="sshPort" value=""/>
    <!-- SSH user name. -->

</applet>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.tightvnc.com/">TightVNC Web Site</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't not work this web, the web page is blank, only show the  `<a href="http://www.tightvnc.com/">TightVNC Web Site</a>` part.

Using `Java Viewer`, I don't need to install the server side([TightVNC for Windows (Version 2.8.11)](https://www.tightvnc.com/download/2.8.11/tightvnc-2.8.11-gpl-setup-64bit.msi))? How do I set up server side?

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to use a browser that supports java applets. Otherwise, the built-in TightVNC-Client will not work and you will only see the line "www.TightVNC.com"

Keep in mind that many browsers don't support java applets (NPAPI) anymore. Chrome stopped support with version 45 (September 2015), Firefox 52 (March 2017), Microsoft Edge doesn't support NPAPI at all.

Try Internet Explorer to check if you installation is correct. Consider a HTML5-based VNC-Client/Viewer.